# How to enable HTML elements on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, servlets

I have a checkbox and a few input elements related to this checkbox as shown below

```
<input name="balanceFeaturesOn" id="balanceFeaturesOn" type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" checked="" />Control
   <input name="IntervalDays26566521" type="Text" onclick="" onchange="" value=" 31 ">
   <input name="IntervalHours26566521" type="Text" onclick="" onchange="" value=" 12 ">
```

For some reasons, I will have to keep my checkbox always disabled.

On the submit of above form (Say that the checkbox and inputs are inside a form), in the server code, I want to grab the text inputs based on if the checkbox was checked/unchecked. However since the checkbox is disabled, the request parameter does not contain the balanceFeaturesOn property.

So when I execute the below line:

```
String[] balanceFeatArr = request.getParameterValues("balanceFeaturesOn");
```

I am not getting any value...

So my question is how do I be able to get the value of the checkbox while still keeping it disabled on the UI?

Comment: So on server check if you have `balanceFeaturesOn` parameter, if so use one text field, otherwise use other.

Comment: yes you can not post a disabled element's value to the server, instead try submitting with js and before submitting remove the disabled attr from it.

Comment: @dfsq - As Jai mentioned, disabled element's value is not sent to the server

Comment: @Arun I know. So I'm saying: if there is no such GET parameter then we know that we need to use this text field. Otherwise other.

Comment: @dfsq - Oh! I got it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code,

In the form use javascript function to submit the form,

```
<input type='submit' onclick='javascript:submitMe()' />
```

Javascript function,

```
function submitMe(){
  $('#balanceFeaturesOn').removeAttr('disabled');
  $('#formId').submit(); //Replace with the actual id of the form
}
```

Make sure you have included ***jquery*** library in your code.

Comment: jqheart - Just in time... I was enabling it back before submit and of course after all my validations pass and exactly before the submit line. And this is working and thanks for the help. I am using jquery and that is why I had tagged this question with jquery along with javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Use Hidden Fields.

Hidden fields are similar to text fields, with one very important difference!

The difference is that the hidden field does not show on the page. Therefore the visitor can't type anything into a hidden field, which leads to the purpose of the field:

To submit information that is not entered by the visitor.

http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms07.htm

Comment: Thanks for the link on html help. A good one and bookmarked it for future use